# How to increment NSIndexPath of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I'm calling this method and nextCellIndexPath is an indexPath greater than the current cell, but the indexPath isn't being properly incremented.

Here is the cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.nextCellIndexPath = indexPath.indexPathByAddingIndex(1)
    return cell
}
```

When I try to scroll to the next indexPath, it appears that the indexPath doesn't increment.

So how do I correctly get the next indexPath?

Comment: It looks like you're assigning `nextCell` to be an `NSIndexPath` instance, not a cell, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. I probably should rename it.

Comment: Is the item already visible on the screen when you call scroll? I think it will only scroll if the item isn't fully visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code: `indexPath.indexPathByAddingIndex(1)` is not doing what you are expecting.  This will add an index to the indexPath, not move to the next row.

Try creating a new NSIndexPath using something like this

```
let nextIndexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: indexPath.section)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks dangerous in terms of dequeue reusable concept. you assign indexPath object to property of reusable cell, you can't be sure, this indexPath will be valid for cell when you're trying to access it from rightBumperTapped method.